# Read data from SOAP XML

Tags: c#, soap

Web request sends to `url` and then response  returns like :

```
- <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 - <soap:Body>
  - <ns2:operationResponse xmlns:ns2="">
    <return>
    <response> 
    <header> 
      <uname></uname> 
      <pass></pass> 
      <sp></sp> 
      <ss></ss> 
      <trx></trx> 
     <headerdtl></headerdtl> 
   </header> 
     <respcd>8913|9|8915|1;Record already existed!!|</respcd> 
     <rcdcnt>0</rcdcnt> 
     </response>
     </return> 
    </ns2:operationResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

what I want is to read `|number|` from `<respcd>8913|number|8915|1;Record already existed!!|</respcd>`

this value not maintain the same, it return 0 or 9. How can I read this value using c#

`Update`

I have this code:

```
   int index = xmlString.IndexOf("<response>");
        xmlString = xmlString.Substring(index, xmlString.Length - index);
        index = xmlString.IndexOf("</return>");
        xmlString = xmlString.Substring(0, index);
```

but an error says : `StartIndex cannot be less than zero`
in this line `xmlString = xmlString.Substring(index, xmlString.Length - index);`

I know the index now is `-1` but it is the actual index of ..Any idea?

Comment: You are just getting back the XML text and want to parse out a specific value?

Comment: there is no need for xml parser or anything, if you add the source of this xml as reference, it will expose a class representation of this xml. From that you can easily access its properties

Comment: I am getting this xml as response and I want to read `|value| from <respcd>8913|value|8915|1;Record already existed!!|</respcd>`

Comment: A web service to which you are applying, must provide the WSDL specification. Using it, you can easily generate client classes by Visual Studio. Do not suffer, use these opportunities.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to load the XML, get the text from the node, and parse out value you want. However, if the value you want is unique enough, you could just use RegEx from the start and forget loading the XML. Here are both methods:

**Load the XML**

```
string soapmessage = @"
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
        <soap:Body>
            <ns2:operationResponse xmlns:ns2='http://someurl.com'>
                <return>
                    <response> 
                        <header> 
                            <uname></uname> 
                            <pass></pass> 
                            <sp></sp> 
                            <ss></ss> 
                            <trx></trx> 
                            <headerdtl></headerdtl> 
                        </header> 
                        <respcd>8913|9|8915|1;Record already existed!!|</respcd> 
                        <rcdcnt>0</rcdcnt> 
                    </response>
                </return> 
            </ns2:operationResponse>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
";

XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(soapmessage);
XmlNodeList xnList = document.SelectNodes("//respcd");
XmlNode node = xnList.Cast<XmlNode>().FirstOrDefault();

string value = Regex.Match(node.InnerText, "(?<=|)[09](?=|)").Value;
Console.WriteLine(value); //<== writes out 9.
```

**Use RegEx Only**

```
string value2 = Regex.Match(soapmessage, "(?<=|)[09](?=|)").Value;
Console.WriteLine(value2); //<== writes out 9.
```

*Note* I change the `xmlns:ns2=""` part to be `xmlns:ns2="http://someurl.com"` because the load XML method was throwing an error because the namespace wasn't properly defined.

Comment: I used first option but it says `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` in this line `string value = Regex.Match(node.InnerText, "(?<=|)[09](?=|)").Value;`

Comment: when I used RegEx, it print `0` while response value is `9`? it did not read actual value from response

Comment: I think it's safer to use the first solution. Use DOM to get the element, read it's value and read out the character you need. If you are in control of the webservice, you could better alter the XSD's so that all the values in <respcd> are seperated in their own elements/attributes.

Comment: @SaifManea the regular expression in my second example would not be returning a `0` if there was not a part of the soap text that looked like `|0|`. Somewhere in your soap message is the text `|0|`. That is the only way it would return anything. Please check your soap message again. Is the example you posted complete? Are there multiple instances of the `<respcd>` node?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 XmlNode nListAuthor = doc.SelectNodes("//respcd")[0];
        string Output = string.Empty;
        if (nListAuthor != null) 
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(nListAuthor.InnerText, @"^(?:[0-9]+\|([0-9])\|[0-9]+\|(.*)\|)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) 
            {
                Output = Regex.Match(nListAuthor.InnerText, @"^(?:[0-9]+\|([0-9])\|[0-9]+\|(.*)\|)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
            } 
        }
```